# Откуда берется org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException?

Tags: java, веб-программирование, postgresql, hibernate

Проходил туториал вот [тут](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/520-vashe-pervoe-prilozhenie-na-hibernate). Но при выполнении данного кода вылезает данная ошибка:

```
`org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 0 and column 0 in RESOURCE hibernate.cfg.xml. Message: null`
```

Stacktrace:

```
org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 0 and column 0 in RESOURCE hibernate.cfg.xml. Message: null
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:258)
    at util.HibernateSessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory(HibernateSessionFactoryUtil.java:18)
    at util.UserDao.update(UserDao.java:36)
    at Managment.UserManager.updateUser(UserManager.java:29)
    at mainpart.UploadDownloadFileServlet.doPost(UploadDownloadFileServlet.java:106)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

Класс, ловящий ошибку:

```
import filemodel.UriStorage;
import filemodel.User;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateSessionFactoryUtil {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private HibernateSessionFactoryUtil() {}

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            try {
                Configuration configuration =
                        new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
                configuration.addAnnotatedClass(User.class);
                configuration.addAnnotatedClass(UriStorage.class);
                StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder =
                        new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
                sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Исключение!" + e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Файл конфига:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">postgres</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Использую java 8.

Подскажите, как лечить и почему возникает даннная ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

Сравните со своим проектом - может найдете отличия, а за ним и ошибку https://github.com/viktorkusliy/ExampleHibernate

Comment: Клонировал репозиторий, привязал к вашему проекту свою бд, которую я делал согласно туториалу и получил тот же exception.

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с таким же Exception при подключений Hibernate , я перерыл практически весь интернет для поиска решения данной проблемы , и по и тогу нашел решение. Предполагаю что проблема заключается в том что Hibernate не может прочитать файл , это может быть вызвано тем что не были импортированы нужные классы для чтения файла а именно **com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory**  что странно для версий Java 8 где jaxb был встроен , в последующих версиях jaxb выпилили из java , и его надо импортировать вручную через Maven.

Мне помогли следующие зависимости Maven :

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.23.1-GA</version>
    </dependency>
```

Последняя зависимость обязательна